# WSO2 esb api does not interpret xml when SOAPAction present

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an Oracle SOA HTTP Binding that sends the XML message into WSO2 ESB. This message (incorrectly) contains a SOAPAction header. When this header is present, ESB gives the error: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found .
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB does not have any issues with processing SOAPAction header. According to the error exception you are getting, it is related to the content-type of your request. Please check on the content-type of the message coming in to ESB. If the content type is text/xml, then ESB expects a SOAP message and in this particular scenario, you will get this exception if the message does not contain the soap header. If it is not a SOAP message, then change the content-type to application/xml.

Comment: ok, then this is the issue - the incoming message is generated by Oracle SOA and sends text/xml. I cannot change this.

Comment: Then you can achieve this by changing the messageBuilder configuration inside the axis2.xml file. Add the below configuration to the message builders section. <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>